# (Not just) running an R script in matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I have an R script that I need to understand better - what it's doing, why it's doing what it's doing, etc. Problem is, I'm not familiar with R. I am, however, familiar with Matlab. So I'm hoping there's a way to port this R script into Matlab such that I can run through this R script in a way how to use different software.

I don't just want to run the R script and have the output sent to Matlab for further use, I want to be able to open an R script in Matlab and be able to treat it like a .m script.

Failing that, at least some way to run through the R script (using R in Windows) that doesn't involve stepping through every single line in debugging and then having to type print([variable name]) at every step to see what the function did.

Comment: If you don't know R, then your best option is basically to read the comments in the code (or ask the person who wrote it), find out what it's doing, and try implementing the same steps in MATLAB. If your output matches, you're probably on the right track.

Comment: Originally asking for help with a Matlab script is how I got the R script in the first place. They're quite busy, so I was provided with an R script that accomplishes the same thing I'm trying to code, but in R, and left to figure it out. I'm just trying to expedite the process somewhat.

Comment: maybe have a quick look [at this equivalence table](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/octave-r.html), but any understanding has to be the result of your own efforts. There's no shortcut.

Comment: @baptiste I know I have to figure it out for myself, and I never intended to do otherwise. I was just significantly hindered by the new keywords/syntax/etc., but that equivalence guide looks to be immensely helpful. Cheers.